not able to interact with monaco editor api in leetcode
I am working on a chrome extension where I want to inject some piece of text into monaco code editor present on leetcode.
I am tring to access the monaco api through chrome extension but I am failing to do so, but if I type window.monaco in console of browser it shows the monaco object.
Following is the code I am using for accessing monaco object
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "LeetCode Template Injector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Insert algorithm templates into LeetCode editor.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://leetcode.com/problems/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}

content.js
function checkMonacoEditor() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (typeof monaco !== "undefined" && monaco.editor.getModels().length > 0) {
      console.log("monaco editor found");
    } else {
      console.log("Waiting for Monaco editor...");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  checkMonacoEditor();
});

Here is a screenshot of my browser console

